# Stop listbox from navigating with arrows C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a canvas which elements can be moved with the arrow keys, however when i select an element in a listbox that is currently on the canvas. The arrow key down will filter down the list until it reaches the bottom then will move the element on the canvas. the other problem is it will then move the element at the very bottom of the listbox that is now selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" PreviewKeyDown="lb_PreviewKeyDown">
    <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void lb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: it worked a treat, thanks for your help. not sure why it was downvoted :)